# UIScrollView content changing its origin point

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm new on iOS Development and I already searched Google many times but didn't find a solution to my problem.

I have a `UITabBar` that has two tabs. The first one shows a `ScrollView` with some `UIViews` in it.
If I scroll the content (the `UIViews`), then change to the second tab and change back to the first tab, the `UIViews` get its origin point changed.

I'm using `NSLog()` to show the origin point of the `UIViews` in the `viewDidAppear` method of my `UIViewController`.
When the view appear the first time, the origin point of the `UIView` is `(0,0)`. After changing the tab and changing back to the first tab, the origin point is set to `(0,-XXX)` where `XXX` is negative and varies depending on how much I have scrolled the content initially.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I couldn't test the solution of resetting the contentOffset because i already changed my interface.
Instead of adding the UIViews with the storyboard tools, i'm adding dinamically in the code.

That prevents me from others problems that i was having...

Anyway, thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with UIScrollViews and the autolayout system.  If you reset the `contentOffset` in `-viewWillAppear` you can work around it:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```